# Laravel Custom Primary Key not working on Data Update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, primary-key, crud

I am trying to make a crud function in laravel with custom primary ID. The Create, Read, and Delete are all working but whenever I tried Update I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `pages` where `slug` = about and `id` <> 3)

Model
**pages.php**

```
class Page extends Model{
use HasFactory;

protected $primaryKey = 'pages_id';

protected $fillable = [
    'is_default_home',
    'is_default_not_found',
    'title',
    'slug',
    'content',
];}
```

Controller
***pages.php***

```
public function update()
{
    $this->validate(); 
    $this->unassignedDefaultHomePage(); 
    $this->unassignedDefaultNotFoundPage(); 
    Page::find($this->modelId)->update($this->modelData());
    $this->modalFormVisible = false;
    $this->reset();
}
```

**Model Data**

```
public function modelData()
{
    return [
        'title' => $this->title,
        'slug' => $this->slug,
        'content' => $this->content,
        'is_default_home' => $this->isSetToDefaultHomePage,
        'is_default_not_found' => $this->isSetToDefaultNotFoundPage,
    ];
}
```

I'm not sure why it finds the column 'id' because I set the $primaryKey in my model as 'pages_id'. I am using phpMyAdmin (xampp).Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check your database table columun id doesn't exists. Create acolumn in database.

```
class Page extends Model{
use HasFactory;

protected $primaryKey = 'pages_id';

protected $fillable = [
    'is_default_home',
    'is_default_not_found',
    'title',
    'slug',
    'content',
];}
```

In Above code `pages_id` prefer to table named `pages` column named `id`. Check these

Comment: comment here if you find same error

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had to change how the id in the database is being read by the count function

Answer (score 0):

This is a error from `count` query, not from `update` query. I think you need check other function. Update function is no problem.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I had to change how the count function reads the id of the table in the database.